# A2P 10DLC Questions & Support

Tags: twilio, twiliosms

This A2P 10DLC process is probably the biggest hassle I have ever had with Twilio. We don't "market" a brand or anything close to that. There is no marketing of a brand at all. We send jobs to our technicians in the field. We send less than 1k a month of texts. With nothing more than "were working on it and it will be weeks before we approve OR deny your registration" to go on I feel LOST and my texts are not gong through reliably anymore.
Is this affecting everyone or just me? Twilio needs to handle this better, come on guys!

Filled out the registration form, however I am still getting notices that I didn't complete it and need to. Go to website, I am told it's under review. So not sure why I am still getting notices.

Comment: A2P 10DLC approval is taking weeks for approvals. You're not the only one facing this issue.

Comment: I registered our numbers more then a month ago. Two days left for the blocking deadline, still pending, come on Twilio!